# Branch Deep Linking(IOS):Not getting Linking parameters by taping post of facebook

Tags: ios

Hello , i am not getting linking parameters when i redirect to app from facebook by taping post.i am using Deep linking in Branch framwork in IOS.

i.e
let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()

```
    branch.initSessionWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { optParams, error in

        if error == nil, let params = optParams {

            print(“params: %@”, params)
```

Response:

[+clicked_branch_link: 0, +is_first_session: 0]

but i always get reponse in

let getFirstReferringParams = branch.getFirstReferringParams()